# How to access the build target name in bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In yocto we build the target by running this command "bitbake target_name".
Is there any global variable where the value of target_name is stored ?
How can i access the target_name in other dependent recipes ?

So i have a hardware for which i can build multiple variants of Linux image. And say these are the different image name "minimal-image debug-image main-image core-image". I'll use bitbake to build one of these image. Now during build time i'll set some particular flags based on which image is being built. So basically i want a means that can get me the details about which image is being built at the build time.

Comment: Generally, you could simply set your own variables in each image's .bb file, and perform a dependency check based on them. This did not work for me, however, not sure why but I did not have time to dig in. By the way, it would be useful for the community if you didn't leave your question open in case you did find a solution or a workaround for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For that use-case, no.  You could be building two images at once.  Packages are built *once* for all images.