# Yocto check which packages are installed on target system

Tags: yocto, bitbake, inspec

I have a `Yocto` system where I'm running some `Chef InSpec` scans. Chef InSpec offers a command to check if a package is installed, however, that doesn't work with Yocto (I imagine it would if you'd install a package manager, but I don't want to do that). What would be the best way to check if a certain package is installed on the system?

I know that `bitbake` can show every package that would be in the built image, but I need to check on the target system. Is there a way I can get this information from `bitbake` from within a recipe that would just route the output into a file on the `rootfs`? Or is there a better approach without installing a package manager on the target system?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the folder `tmp/deploy/images/$MACHINE/${IMAGE}/`
You should see a file named with manifest extension. It is often named like this : [image-name]-[image-version].manifest"

In this file you will find all packages that are present in your linux image built with Yocto, so packages that will be deployed in your target.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to check the installed packages on the target system, as in I need access to which packages are installed from the running target system, not the host environment, which is why I'm asking how to do this without a package manager on the Yocto system. I thought about writing a recipe to copy the appropriate manifest file over, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054642/how-to-access-the-build-target-name-in-bitbake it isn't trivial to get the image name in a variable for a recipe.

Comment: If you use the IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND (Check documentation...) variable to add a command to do this, it'll probably work to copy it into the rootfs somewhere...  POSTPROCESS is not likely to work- that's kind of late-ish for doing what you're trying for.